# When can C# infer the type of a parameter?

Tags: c#, type-inference

Why does the following correctly infer the type of T:

```
void foo<T>(IEnumerable<T> src){
  src.Select(id => id);
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
Func<T, T> Id<T>() {
  return (T t) => t;
}

void foo() {
  new List<int>().Select(Id());
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Type argument inference always works on method arguments - including the first argument to an extension method like `Select`.

So your second call is effectively:

```
Enumerable.Select(new List<int>(), Id())
```

`Select` will be able to use those arguments to infer the type argument there, but the `Id()` call doesn't have any arguments, and type inference doesn't try to work out what the type argument should be based on how the method is *used*.

In other words, it's not `Select` that's the problem here - it's `Id()`. So this would work:

```
// No type inference available
var idFunc = Id<int>();
// Type argument to Select is inferred
var selection = new List<int>.Select(idFunc);
```

Comment: Thank you. Select does however work out the type arguments of the anonymous function passed in, and is able to infer that with `t => t` I mean `(int t) => t` or rather `Func<int, int> (int t) => t`. I'm going to take some time to get my head around how exactly that is different - I have the feeling it's because against my initial intuation `t => t` is never actually a parameterized type but is directly inferred to be a "simple" type.

Comment: @Martijn: Do you mean in your first example? In that case, the argument is a lambda expression, and the first type argument is inferred from the type of `src`. Note that `t => t` is *just* a lambda expression; it doesn't have a type as such, but can be converted to delegate or expression tree types. Type inference does cunning things to work out which types are involved - so in `src.Select(id => id)`, the first type argument is inferred to be `T` (the same as for the method) and then the lambda expression is examined with that information known, so the return type is inferred to be `T` too.

Comment: Yes. I think that's the crux of things for me: A lambda expression is *not* an anonymous function (but the compiler can construct one from it, and has more tools to do inference there than on a parameterized method). Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Martijn: No, a lambda expression *is* an anonymous function, as is an anonymous method. That's the definition of "anonymous function", in the C# specification. But again, "anonymous function" isn't a particular type - it's something that can be converted to specific types. I'm not quite sure what you were trying to say...

Comment: Aaargh. I'll get in to the spec, and just read more rather than asking questions and confusing terminology. I was at the point where I tought a lamba is an (untyped)expression that can be turned in to a (typed) anonymous function, but doesn't become a parameterised function in between.

Comment: @Martijn, the main difference is that C# cannot infer if a generic type parameter is used solely in the return type. So, for instance, if ID is the function itself instead of building one, e.g. `T ID<T>(T t) { return t; }`, then `.Select(ID)` will work just as well as with the lambda

Answer (score 1):

> Section 7.4.2 Type Inference
>
> **If the supplied number of arguments is different than the number of
>   parameters in the method, then inference immediately fails.** Otherwise,
>   assume that the generic method has the following signature:
>
> Tr M(T1 x1 … Tm xm)
>
> With a method call of the form M(E1 …Em) the task of type inference is
>   to find unique type arguments S1…Sn for each of the type parameters
>   X1…Xn so that the call M(E1…Em)becomes valid.

This code should work fine:

```
Func<T, T> Id<T>()
{
       return (T t) => t;
}

void foo()
{
      new List<int>().Select(Id<int>());
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is particularly helpful without any explanation.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, OP asks about _why_ type inference didn't worked. He obviously knows he could specify the T type.

Comment: Id() call doesn't have any arguments

Comment: I probably should have been more verbose, the question really was why doesn't C# infer the type parameter of Id

Comment: I wasn't asking for code that works in the question.

Comment: @isxaker how about you edit the question and addsome explanation? it only takes a moment, and can get you upvotes rather than downvotes.